# How can I see all the latest comments?

Tags: support, comments

I can see the latest questions on https://money.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Newest. I can see the latest question or answer activity on https://money.stackexchange.com/questions?tab=Active. But how can I see all the latest comments?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [Charcoal team](https://charcoal-se.org) has developed a great tool called Blaze that does exactly this.

If you access https://charcoal-se.org/blaze/#site=money you'll see something like this:

> [image]

Upon choosing "comments", you'll get the list of comments like this:

> [image]

As you can see, it allows to auto refresh every certain seconds, so it is a great tool to monitor what is being said in a given site.

Note the timestamp is actually a link to the comment.

Comment: this was downvoted... 

Comment: Perhaps you could mention that the timestamp is actually a link to the comment. This tripped me up *twice*. Each time, I forgot.

Comment: @Flux sure, done.

Answer (score 7):

There's no view that displays the most recent comments. However, this information is available through the API, via https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/comments?order=desc&sort=creation&site=money, even without an app.

If you want a nice, graphical view of it, see fedorqui's answer.

For Meta Stack Overflow, the [boson](https://stackapps.com/questions/8042/boson-track-anything-anywhere) bot has been used to repost all comments to [this chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197298/meta-stack-overflow-comment-archive), which makes it easy to get a view of the most recent comments. I'm pretty sure it can easily be adapted to another site, if you want an archive and not a real-time view (an archive doesn't update on edits or deletions).